# Why am i'm getting 0/0 error with my sql query?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

The following query is giving me an error of 0/0, which i know is not the case. anyone know why this may be?

i'm essentially looking for the engagement rate (likes+comments_views/followers) by username

| id | average_likes | average_comments | average_views | followers_count | username |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | 50 | 5 | 5 | 100 | abc |
| 234 | 35 | 5 | 5 | 80 | sdf |

```
select (sum(average_likes + average_comments + average_views)/sum(followers_count)), username FROM 
`public_instagram_channels` as pic
group by username
```

Answer (score 0):

Obviously, `sum(followers_count)` can be zero.  There are a couple of solution, but a typical uses `NULLIF()`:

```
select (sum(average_likes + average_comments + average_views) /
        nullif(sum(followers_count), 0)
       ), username 
from `public_instagram_channels` pic
group by username
```

Comment: does nullif work with BIgQuery? i tried to add it in, but got a syntax error. and thank you for the help!

Comment: @michelle . . . Yes.  `NULLIF()` is a standard SQL function and supported in BigQuery and almost every other database as well:  https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators#nullif.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select CASE sum(followers_count) WHEN 0 THEN 0 ELSE sum(average_likes + average_comments + average_views) /
       sum(followers_count)
       ) END, username 
from `public_instagram_channels` pic
group by username
```

Answer (score 0):

Big fan of [SAFE_DIVIDE()](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators#safe_divide) here...

```
with user_agg as (
    select username, sum(average_likes + average_comments + average_views) as numerator, sum(followers_count) as denominator
    from `public_instagram_channels`
    group by 1
)
select username, safe_divide(numerator,denominator) as solution
from user_agg
```

Comment: thanks!  i wanted to add a clause that only divdes if follower_count is > 10000, but when i put it at the end (after from user_agg), i can't seem to get the query to work anymore. the query i used is "where followers_count >10000"

Comment: ah, that was because i explicitly named that column `denominator` in the CTE to illustrate the `SAFE_DIVIDE` concept.  On line 2, where I name the two sums `numerator` and `denominator`, you might want to change to `engagements` (or whatever) and `follower_count`.  Then you can use your proposed where filter.